# select multiple columns from mutiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Example.
I have two tables

```
CAR
id  name
1    bmw
2    fiat

Car_info
car_id  field_name   country
  1     year          2000
  1     country       germany
  2     year          1988
  2     country       italy
```

How in one select query I can get this?

```
id name  year  country
1   bmw  2000   germany
2   fiat 1988   italy
```

Comment: Why does your `country` column on Car_info contain years as well as contries? Shouldn't that column be named `field_val`, since it's name is being set at, well, `field_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should have a column in the car_info table specifying what type of information is being displayed on that line. i.e. Type 1 is the year, type 2 is the country.

You can get round this by joining on to the car_info table twice specifying an 'AND' condition on the join, like so:

```
SELECT car.ID, car.Name, ci1.country as [YEAR], ci2.country as COUNTRY
FROM car
INNER JOIN car_info AS ci1 ON Car.ID = ci1.car_id AND ci1.field_name = 'year'
INNER JOIN car_info AS ci2 ON Car.ID = ci2.car_id AND ci2.field_name = 'country'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH car AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'BMW' AS name FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Fiat' FROM dual
)
, car_info AS (
  SELECT 1 AS car_id, 'Year' AS field_name, '2000' AS field_val FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Country', 'Germany' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Year', '1988' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Country', 'Italy' FROM dual
)
  SELECT c.*, car_year.field_val AS yr, car_country.field_val AS country
    FROM car c
    JOIN car_info car_year ON c.id = car_year.car_id AND car_year.field_name = 'Year'
    JOIN car_info car_country ON c.id = car_country.car_id AND car_country.field_name = 'Country'
;
```

Comment: `dual` ? It's an oracle query. OP wants the answer in `sql server`

Comment: Then forget about the `dual` part. Run the query from the main `SELECT c.*` onwards. You'll get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
You can use `PIVOT` and then join with the `Car` table

```
with cte as 
(
 Select car_id,[year],[country]
 from 
 (Select car_id,field_name,countryName
  from car_info
 )pv
 pivot 
 (
  max(countryName)
  FOR field_name IN ([year],[country])
 )pvt
 )
 Select c.name,ct.year,ct.country
 from car c inner join cte ct
 on ct.car_id=c.id
```

Demo in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/949f7/1)